# Expresión regular en javascript que solo permita palabras y un espacio entre palabras y ningún espacio inicial o final

Tags: javascript, html5, regex

Por favor amigos cómo puedo validar una cadena de texto que empiece con letras y termine con letras, pero es valido solo un espacio entre las palabras.
Estos fueron mis intentos:
1.Esto acepta solo letras y con su respectivo acento de las vocales y no permite ningún numero ni caracteres especiales. Ahora solo me falta controlar los espacios en blanco.

```
if (!/^[a-zA-Z\ áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚñÑ\s]*$/.test(caracter2)){
   permitidos=false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ATENCIÓN AMIGOS, encontre otra solución el cual es internamente, al final lo que se aguarde en la BD será lo siguiente, ejemplo: `'  Hola  amigos  que tal '` en este ejemplo estoy dejando espacios en blanco y eliminaremos todos quedaría así: `'Hola amigos que tal'` favor si encuentran la solución publiquenla. Gracias.
Forma más corta: str = string.replace(/^\s+|\s+$|\s+(?=\s)/g, "");

```js
document.getElementById("nombre_1").onkeypress = function(){
        return permite(event,'car')
    }
function permite(elEvento,permitidos) {
switch(permitidos) {
case 'car':
     var evento2 =elEvento || window.event;
 var codigoCaracter2 = evento2.charCode || evento2.keyCode;
var caracter2 = String.fromCharCode(codigoCaracter2);

var string="  Hola   amigos  que  tal  ";
                   
string3= string.trim().replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ');
                   
 console.log(string3);
 console.log(caracter2);
 
                
 if(!/^[a-zA-ZáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚñÑ /s]*$/.test(caracter2)){
     permitidos = false;
 }
                     
 return permitidos;
     break;  
   }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Nombre" id="nombre_1" maxlength="30" required>
```

Answer (score 2):

con la funcion `trim()` eliminas los espacios del comienzo y del final, quedaria.

```
if (!/^[a-zA-Z\ áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚñÑ\s]*$/.test(caracter2.trim())){
   permitidos=false;
}
```

Comment: Esta bien amigo eso lo haría internamente en código pero aún así necesito controlar los espacios en blanco que hay entre las palabras. ¿Cómo hago eso?

Comment: prueba con esta exprsiony me cuentas, que tal te va... ^\w+(\s\w+)*$

Comment: No funciona y permite números

Comment: muy raro, segun lo indagado, dice que si, revisa esta pagina, el ultimo comentario y te ayudara https://code.i-harness.com/es/q/ec187c

Comment: Amigo jejejje en esa pagina ya estuve también pensé que funcionaria pero no es raro ya que en mi código no funciona y ya lo probé aquí y si funciona. Imagino que es  el hecho de estar evaluando por caracter: https://regex101.com/r/27ijuN/3

Comment: si, es lo mas seguro

Answer (score 1):

Esta expresión regular debería cumplir con tus criterios de

- Debe empezar por letra y terminar por letra
- Las palabras deben separarse como mucho por un espacio

`^[a-zA-ZáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚñÑ]+(?: [a-zA-ZáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚñÑ]+)*$`

Explicación:

Busca al inicio que empiece por una palabra (letras repetidas 1 o más veces) a continuación, se repite el siguiente conjunto: ( un espacio + una palabra ) de cero a varias veces. Finalmente, debe terminar con fin de línea/string.

Puedes ver un ejemplo aquí: https://regex101.com/r/ZeiIM4/1/

Answer (score 0):

Amigos por favor ayúdenme: hasta ahora solo es conseguido bloquear los espacios en blanco de inicio y final y no permite números ni caracteres especiales. Falta controlar los espacios en blanco entre palabras.

Mi codigo

```js
document.getElementById("nombre_1").onkeypress = function(){
        return permite(event,'car')
}


function permite(elEvento,permitidos) {
  switch(permitidos) {         
    case 'car':
var evento2 = elEvento || window.event;
var codigoCaracter2 = evento2.charCode || evento2.keyCode;
var caracter2 = String.fromCharCode(codigoCaracter2);
                    
                
if(!/^[a-zA-ZáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚñÑ]+(\s\w+)*$/.test(caracter2)){
   permitidos = false;
}
  return permitidos;
              break;  
        }    
    }
```

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Nombre" id="nombre_1" maxlength="30" required>
```